# CS50 pset1 Greedy Challenge

Tags: c, greedy, cs50

I'm a bit ashamed for asking this silly question here, but the fact is, I've tried everything and I still can't see where the error is.

I'm 101% noob as regards programming, and I've enrolled in CS50. I'm trying to get the best out of it, so I'm taking the less comfortable challenges always so as to try and learn the most.

I've finished my code for the Greedy Challenge in CS50's pset1. I've squished my mind in order to get it as good, clean and simple as my humble knowledge allows me to, but I keep getting prompted just one error every time I check my code.

Hereby I attach both, the code check and my wirtten code:

Checked code by CS50 terminal script:

`:) greedy.c exists
 :) greedy.c compiles
 :) input of 0.41 yields output of 4
 :) input of 0.01 yields output of 1
 :) input of 0.15 yields output of 2
 :) input of 1.6 yields output of 7
 :( input of 23 yields output of 92
    \ expected output, but not "94\n"
 :) input of 4.2 yields output of 18
 :) rejects a negative input like -.1
 :) rejects a non-numeric input of "foo"
 :) rejects a non-numeric input of ""`

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

float change;

int coins = 0;
int quantity;

int main (void)
{
do 
{
    printf("O hai! How much change is owed?\n");
    change = get_float();
}
while (change < 0);



//converting float change (dollars) into integer change (cents)

 quantity = round(change * 100.00);



while (quantity > 25) //This runs as long as quantity left is bigger than a quarter coin
{
    quantity -= 25;
    coins++;
}
while (quantity >= 10) //This runs as long as quantity left is bigger than a dime coin
{
    quantity -= 10;
    coins++;
}
while (quantity >= 5) //This runs as long as quantity left is bigger than a nickel coin
{
    quantity -= 5;
    coins++;
    }
while (quantity >= 1) //This runs as long as quantity left is bigger than 0
{
    quantity -= 1;
    coins++;
}


printf("%i\n", coins);
}`
```

**Disclaimer**: I want to point out that I'm perfectly aware of Harvard's Code of Honesty. I'm not trying to get an easy solution for a problem and just get rid of this challenge.

I'm hoping for someone to take his or her own time and write down an explanation that enlightens me and helps me understand the **whys** of my code failure. 
I don't seek any answer, and you don't have to point it out if you don't feel like so.
I'm just an inexperienced beginner student in CS who's willing to read all your answers and finally gets to understand why something that's supposed to work isn't working at all.

Thank you very much for your patience and time!

Comment: `quantity > 25` --> `quantity >= 25`

Comment: What output do you get for 0.25?

Comment: 1! Right now solved! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your very first comparison that reads `(quantity > 25)`. When you have a grand sum of $23 you expect `23 * 4 = 92 coins`.

However, when you have subtracted 91 of those quarters you end up with `(quantity == 25)` and the check fails (since the `quantity` is no longer **strictly bigger** than `25` but is equal to it), pushing you through into 2 dimes and then into the last nickel, making it a displayed 94 coins.

The fix is (you should have guessed it by now) to replace that check with `(quantity >= 25)`

Comment: Oh, I see!!!! Thank you so much @YePhIcK!! 

I understand where the problem is. Very gently explained! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <math.h>

    float change; // change can be float

    int amount;

    int coins = 0;

    int main(void)
   {

       do
       {
           change = get_float ("Change owed: ");
       }
       while(change < 0);

       amount = round(change * 100);

       while( amount >= 25)
      {
           amount -= 25;//This is the end of loop substract until it reaches to the 
           //25 or less
           coins ++;// this is the count of coins that how many owned coins will 
           //become big bite
       }

       while(amount >= 10)
       {
           amount -= 10;
           coins ++;
       }

       while(amount >= 5)
       {
           amount-=5;
           coins++;
       }
       while(amount >= 1)
       {
       amount -= 1;
       coins++;
   }

   printf("The minimum number of coins that is to be used is: %i",coins);//the minimum number of coins
   printf(" coins.");
   printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: Answers consisting of only code are not quality answers. Please edit your post to explain what you changed and why you changed it.